# ROC Curve in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, roc, proc-r-package

I am trying to render roc curve using shiny. I tried using both pROC and ROCR packages, and using renderPlot, but the outputplot showing NULL. Is there any way to render ROC Curve in shiny app?

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to use `plot()` on the ROC object inside the `renderPlot` function. Here is a working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(pROC)        

ui <- shinyUI(
  plotOutput('myplot')
)

server <- function(input, output)
{
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    my_roc <- pROC::roc(c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0))
    plot(my_roc)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @md-faisal-akbar, glad I could help. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to mark your question as resolved, thanks!